# LGHT0001 : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: wix

I've googled the problem for hours but without finding any solution.

I'm using Wix 3.14 and every time I build on a build server I get this error. When I build locally on my computer, then it works every time, but never on the build server.

I build an msi-file and then bundle with another installation package to the setup executable.

```
2019-01-31T10:25:46.2328162Z Moving file 'D:\agent\_work\_temp\1jjhaplm\1jjhaplm\setup-bundle.exe' to 'D:\agent\_work\18\a\dist\setup-bundle.exe'.
2019-01-31T10:25:51.2172314Z light.exe : error LGHT0001 : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

This is how I build the package:

```
heat dir ./source -var var.SourceDir -cg MainComponentGroup -platform=x64 -dr INSTALLLOCATION -sreg -gg -o files.wxs
candle -arch x64 -dSourceDir=source -ext WixUtilExtension -ext WixUIExtension ambr.wxs files.wxs
light -ext WixUtilExtension  -ext WixUIExtension ambr.wixobj files.wixobj -o setup.msi
candle -arch x64 -dSourceDir=source -ext WixUtilExtension -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixBalExtension Bundle.wxs
light -v -ext WixUtilExtension -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixBalExtension Bundle.wixobj -o setup-bundle.exe
```

The bundle.wxs file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
   xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
   xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
   xmlns:vi="http://schemas.visualinstaller.de/VisualInstallerWixExtension">

  <?define UmRes="..\setup-utils\"?>
  <?define UmVersionInfoMajor="1"?>
  <?define UmVersionInfoMinor="0"?>
  <?define UmVersionInfoRevision="0"?>
  <?define PlatformGuidPart="BB64"?>
  <?define GUID_BundleProduct="{206E1EC4-3377-$(var.UmVersionInfoMajor)$(var.UmVersionInfoMinor)$(var.UmVersionInfoRevision)0-$(var.PlatformGuidPart)-000F000F1337}" ?>

  <?define Platform="x64"?>
  <?define Configuration="release"?>
  <?define UmCompilerVersion="vc140"?>
  <?define OutDir="."?>
  <?define UmProduct="The product"?>
  <?include CommonIncludes.wxi ?>

  <!-- Add minor version to some strings if the minor version is != 0. -->
  <?if $(var.UmVersionInfoMinor) = "0" ?>
  <!-- The format of the product name in GUI -->
  <?define UmProd-display="$(var.UmProduct) $(var.UmVersionInfoMajor)" ?>
  <!-- The format for the version number in the setup program. -->
  <?define UmSetupVersion="$(var.UmVersionInfoMajor)"?>
  <?else ?>
  <?define UmProd-display="$(var.UmProduct) $(var.UmVersionInfoMajor).$(var.UmVersionInfoMinor)" ?>
  <?if $(var.UmVersionInfoRevision) = "0" ?>
  <?define UmSetupVersion="$(var.UmVersionInfoMajor)_$(var.UmVersionInfoMinor)"?>
  <?else ?>
  <?define UmSetupVersion="$(var.UmVersionInfoMajor)_$(var.UmVersionInfoMinor)_$(var.UmVersionInfoRevision)"?>
  <?endif ?>
  <?endif ?>

  <?define UmSetupName="$(var.UmSuiteName) $(var.UmProduct)" ?>
  <?define UmProductVersion="$(var.UmVersionInfoMajor).$(var.UmVersionInfoMinor).$(var.UmVersionInfoRevision).$(var.UmVersionInfoBuild)" ?>
  <?define MongoDBMSI="mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.6.9-signed.msi" ?>
  <?define VCRedistSetup="VC_redist.x64.exe" ?>
  <?define AMBRMSI="setup.msi" ?>

  <Bundle Name="$(var.UmSetupName)" Version="$(var.UmVersionInfoMajor).$(var.UmVersionInfoMinor).$(var.UmVersionInfoRevision).$(var.UmVersionInfoBuild)"
    Manufacturer="$(var.UmLegalName)"
    UpgradeCode="$(var.GUID_BundleProduct)"
    >

  <!--<Update Location="http://test.laika42.com/UpdateInfo.xml"/>-->

  <!-- Payload, that has to be added to run the boostrapper application -->
  <!-- <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id='ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost'>
    <PayloadGroupRef Id='VisualInstallerRuntimeFiles'/>
  </BootstrapperApplicationRef> -->

  <Variable Name="INSTALLDIR" bal:Overridable='no' Value='[$(var.UmProgramFilesFolder)]$(var.UmSuiteName)\$(var.UmProd-display)'/>
  <Variable Name="MONGODBINSTALLDIR" bal:Overridable='yes' Value='[$(var.UmProgramFilesFolder)]\MongoDB\Server\3.6'/>

  <Variable Name="PRODUCTVERSION" bal:Overridable='no' Value='$(var.UmProductVersion)'/>
  <Variable Name="PRODUCTNAME" bal:Overridable='no' Value='$(var.UmProduct)'/>
  <Variable Name="ADDLOCAL" Type="string" Value="all" Persisted="yes" bal:Overridable='yes'/>
  <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id='WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense'>
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
        LicenseFile="General License Terms.rtf"
        />
  </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
  <Log/>
  <Chain>
    <PackageGroupRef Id="redist_vc140" />
    <MsiPackage SourceFile='$(var.MongoDBMSI)' Compressed="yes" >
      <MsiProperty Name='INSTALLLOCATION' Value='[MONGODBINSTALLDIR]'/>
      <MsiProperty Name='SHOULD_INSTALL_COMPASS' Value='0'/>
    </MsiPackage>
    <MsiPackage SourceFile='$(var.AMBRMSI)'/>
  </Chain>
  </Bundle>

  <!-- Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017 -->
   <!-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/redistributing-visual-cpp-files?view=vs-2017 -->
   <Fragment>
      <util:RegistrySearch Id="VCRedist"
         Root="HKLM"
         Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\$(var.Platform)"
         Value="Version" 
         Variable="VCRedistVersion"
      />
      <!-- the result in VCRedistVersion looks like this: v14.16.27012.00 -->

      <PackageGroup Id="redist_vc140">
         <ExePackage Id="vc140" Cache="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" Compressed="yes"
            SourceFile="$(var.VCRedistSetup)"
            Name="VC_redist.$(var.Platform).exe"
            InstallCommand="/install /quiet /norestart"
            InstallCondition="(NOT VCRedistVersion >= v14.16.27012.00) OR NOT VCRedistVersion"
         />
         <!-- NOTE: When Visual Studio is updated with a new version of the bundled redist, the above path will no longer be correct, resulting in a build error.
                    That is a trigger for you, the developer, to update the version number both in SourceFile, and in InstallCondition -->
      </PackageGroup>
   </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

How to fix this or find out what the problem is?

Comment: One of the most likely causes is that you run an AV on the build server which has the file open, while Light tries to access it. You could run [ProcessMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to determine the process(es) that open the file.

Comment: Ok, I understand, you're probably right. Is there a way to add some delay before copying the file, if it's AV that interferes with the file? I guess that we don't want to turn off AV on the build server.. Or some other workaround?